# PostgreSQL BETWEEN operator behaving differently

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I was using a sql query to pull a couple of days' data of a deployed solution

And I was using the query in following manner

```
select column1, column2, column3, column 4 
where <condition 1> AND <condition 2> AND 
      created_timestamp BETWEEN '05-31-2019' AND '06-11-2019'
```

Now it used to fetch the values of all the columns and was filtering the data by the conditions as expected, except there was one twist here. It was not fetching data for the date 11<sup>th</sup> of June which is being provided as the upper limit.

Now as far as I know between operator includes both the endpoints of the range being provided.

What confused me more was that it was somehow including the data for the date 31<sup>st</sup> of may which is the upper limit.

1. I need to know whether or not between operator(especially in postgresql don't think so it will change just want to confirm) includes end points of the range?
2. Even if it includes/excludes it should behave same for both the end points I do not understand the biased behavior any one having a clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `created_timestamp` is a `timestamp` (with or without time zone).

The literal you used, `06-11-2019`, corresponds to midnight on that date:

```
SELECT '06-11-2019'::timestamp with time zone;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2019-06-11 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

So it is not surprising that the results don't include the data from June 11th.

There are two ways forward:

1. Use the next day and the `<` operator:

   ```
   ... WHERE created_timestamp >= '05-31-2019' AND created_timestamp < '06-12-2019'
   ```
2. convert the timestamp to a `date`:

   ```
   ... WHERE date(created_timestamp) BETWEEN '05-31-2019' AND '06-11-2019'
   ```

The second option cannot use an index on `created_timestamp` (but it can use an index on `date(created_timestamp)`).

Your query depends on the PostgreSQL setting of `DateStyle`, so make sure that that setting is always the way you need it.

Comment: Yes you are correct it is a timestamp(without time zone)

so you mean to say that 'BETWEEN' operator will basically convert to this


05-31-2019 00:00:00.00 <= Value >= 06-11-2019 00:00:00.00

is that so?

Comment: In essence yes, except you got the right inequality sign wrong - it should be `<=`.

Comment: Ahh yes I didn't see that, thanks!!

Thanks for clarifying the confusion it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using proper date literals:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM your_table
WHERE created_timestamp BETWEEN '2019-05-31' AND '2019-06-11';
```

`2019-05-31` is in the ISO 8601 format, and unambiguously means May 31, 2019 in any mode.

You may read more about the rules for date/time types [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html).

**Edit:**

The reason why data from 11-June are not showing up is that using `2011-06-11` as the upper bound in the range is the same as using `2011-06-11 00:00:00`.  That is, it only includes 11-June exactly at midnight.  To mitigate this, use 12-June as the upper bound:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM your_table
WHERE created_timestamp >= '2019-05-31' AND created_timestamp < '2019-06-12';
```

Answer (score 1):

If created_timestamp is a date/time value, rather than just a date, then everything on June 11 after midnight (00:00 hours) will be outside the BETWEEN. So you can do this maybe

```
date_trunc('day', created_timestamp) BETWEEN '2019-05-31' AND '2019-06-11'
```

As already pointed out the dates should be yyyy-mm-dd format. They don't need to be cast to date in this case as Gordon mentioned, but he's right in that in some situations you do need to cast to date and it doesn't hurt to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `created_timestamp` is actually in a date/time format.  So, compare to date/time values, not strings:

```
created_timestamp >= '2019-05-21'::date and
created_timestamp < '2019-06-11'::date
```

Note that I changed the `between` to two inequalities.  That means that the codes behaves as expected when `created_timestamp` actually has a time component.

Comment: But PostgreSQL can cast string literals (type `unknown`) to `timestamp`.